# How to analyze a string in java to make sure that it has both letters and numbers?

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement, comparison-operators

I need to analyze a string in JAVA to find out if it has both letters and numbers. So this is what I have so far.
The variable pass is a String of maximum 8 characters/numbers that is inputted by the user.

```
if(pass.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]"))

{

System.out.println("Valid"); 

}

else

{

   System.out.println("Invalid");

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous.

If you just want to know whether the string contains letters or numbers (but perhaps **only** letters or **only** numbers) and nothing else, then the regex :

```
pass.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

will return true.

If you want to check whether it contains **both** letters and numbers, and nothing else, then it is more complex, but something like:

```
pass.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*(([a-zA-Z][0-9])|([0-9][a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

all the best

Comment: Used this and it worked, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`StringUtils.isAlphanumeric`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric%28java.lang.String%29).  Your code will look like this:

```
if (StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(pass)) {
    //valid
} ...
```

You say you also want a maximum of 8 characters.  You can do it like this:

```
if (StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(pass) && StringUtils.length(pass) <= 8) {
    //valid
} ...
```

The advantage of using StringUtils again for the length is that you won't get a NullPointerException if `pass` is null.  Alternatively, you could just use `pass.length()`, but you risk getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks or the help but rolfl got it for me, thanks a ton for the input though!