# Regex to match if string *only* contains *all* characters from a character set, plus an optional one

Tags: java, regex, string

I ran into a wee problem with Java regex. (I must say in advance, I'm not very experienced in either Java or regex.)

I have a string, and a set of three characters. I want to find out if the string is built from **only** these characters. Additionally (just to make it even more complicated), two of the characters **must** be in the string, while the third one is **optional*.

I do have a solution, my question is rather if anyone can offer anything better/nicer/more elegant, because this makes me cry blood when I look at it...

#### The set-up

- There mandatory characters are: `|` (pipe) and `-` (dash).

  The string in question should be built from a combination of these. They can be in any order, but **both have to be in it**.
- The optional character is: `:` (colon).

  The string **can** contain colons, but it **does not have to**. This is the only other character allowed, apart from the above two.
- Any other characters are **forbidden**.

#### Expected results

Following strings should work/not work:

```
"------" = false
"||||" = false
"---|---" = true
"|||-|||" = true
"--|-|--|---|||-" = true
```

...and...

```
"----:|--|:::|---::|" = true
":::------:::---:---" = false
"|||:|:::::|" = false
"--:::---|:|---G---n" = false
```

...etc.

#### The "ugly" solution

Now, I have a solution that seems to work, based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430779/6078214). The reason I'd like a better one will become obvious when you've recovered from seeing this:

```
if (string.matches("^[(?\\:)?\\|\\-]*(([\\|\\-][(?:\\:)?])|([(?:\\:)?][\\|\\-]))[(?\\:)?\\|\\-]*$") || string.matches("^[(?\\|)?\\-]*(([\\-][(?:\\|)?])|([(?:\\|)?][\\-]))[(?\\|)?\\-]*$")) {

    //do funny stuff with a meaningless string

} else {

   //don't do funny stuff with a meaningless string

}
```

#### Breaking it down

The first regex

```
 "^[(?\\:)?\\|\\-]*(([\\|\\-][(?:\\:)?])|([(?:\\:)?][\\|\\-]))[(?\\:)?\\|\\-]*$"
```

checks for all three characters

The next one

```
"^[(?\\|)?\\-]*(([\\-][(?:\\|)?])|([(?:\\|)?][\\-]))[(?\\|)?\\-]*$"
```

check for the two mandatory ones only.

...Yea, I know...

But believe me I tried. Nothing else gave the desired result, but allowed through strings without the mandatory characters, etc.

#### The question is...

Does anyone know how to do it a simpler / more elegant way?

***Bonus question***: There is one thing I don't quite get in the regexes above (more than one, but this one bugs me the most):

As far as I understand(?) regular expressions, `(?\\|)?` should mean that the character `|` is either contained or not (unless I'm very much mistaken), still in the above setup it seems to enforce that character. This of course suits my purpose, but I cannot understand why it works that way.

So if anyone can explain, what I'm missing there, that'd be real great, besides, this I suspect holds the key to a simpler solution (checking for both mandatory and optional characters in one regex would be ideal.

Thank you all for reading (and suffering ) through my question, and even bigger thanks for those who reply. :)

#### PS

I did try stuff like `^[\\|\\-(?:\\:)?)]$`, but that would not enforce **all** mandatory characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a lookahead based regex.

```
^(?=.*\\|)(?=.*-)[-:|]+$
```

or

```
^(?=.*\\|)[-:|]*-[-:|]*$
```

or

```
^[-:|]*(?:-:*\\||\\|:*-)[-:|]*$
```

[DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/lO6gQ3/1)
[DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/lO6gQ3/2)

- `(?=.*\\|)` expects atleast one pipe.
- `(?=.*-)` expects atleast one hyphen.
- `[-:|]+` any char from the list one or more times.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: +1, and just for fun: Wouldn't a couple of lookbehinds be a wee bit more efficient? Then the hurdle of "just these three" has been passed. ;-)

Comment: When there are just 2 required charcters it can be solved, with moderate effort, without lookbefore/lookbehind as well.

Comment: This is what I meant: `^[-:|]+(?<=.*\\|)(?<=.*-)$` - please check.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for your answer, and even more for the demo link, it makes learning regex a lot easier!

I will read more about lookaheads/behinds, never been too familiar with 'em. 

(Although after today's experience I'm not sure I every want to touch a regex again, my eyes are still in pain. Crying blood is not fun.)

Comment: @laune if i remember correctly, java doesn't support infinite-width lookbehind

Comment: Regexes are awesome stuff, go and learn. I'll always be with u.. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj you could improve performance a little bit by using negated character class like `^(?=[^|\\s]*\|)(?=[^-\\s]*-)[-:|]+$`

Comment: @laune Your version throws the following exception (Android Studio 1.5):

`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 16: ^[-:|]+(?<=.*\|)(?<=.*-)$`

Comment: @SebastianProske why a negative char class? `^(?=[-:]*\\|)(?=[|:]*-)[-:|]+$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj because that's the way, I usually use for those check-existance tasks - in this special case, yours will work prefectly as well and should be a bit mire readable. The main point im after is not to use `.*`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj. :) Yea, it's quite interesting. and the "problem" is, I catch myself enjoying it at times. That worries me. ;)

Comment: This site is awesome. This was my first question and I learned more from this thread in 10 minutes than I did all week about regex. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer:

```
(?=.*\|.*-|.*-.*\|)^([-|:]+)$
```

This says that the string needs to have a '-' followed by '|', or a '|' followed by a '-', via the look-ahead. Then the string only matches the allowed characters.

Demo: http://fiddle.re/1hnu96

Comment: Cool solution. This lookahead can be quite useful in other situations too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one without lookbefore and -hind.

```
 ^[-:|]*\\|[-:|]*-[-:|]*|[-:|]*-[-:|]*\\|[-:|]*$
```

This doesn't scale, so Avinash's solution is to be preferred - if your regex system has the lookbe*.